# dealing with #create as json with Rails 4, dropzone.js, carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, dropzone.js

Using [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/)

```
Started POST "/photos"
Processing by PhotosController#create as JSON
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4ZYgROGmbmA7znV9JAG7rfzVhDLfcaDoAVHVJtvj0Il5EEgBDaPCBk99HLaVKxfl69o+cs/aZgpch2Hj5kR7dw==", "photo"=>{"user_id"=>"2"}, "file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fd784bb2ef8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20160814-13-1roacdt.JPG>, @original_filename="DSCN2462.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"DSCN2462.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}
[1mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", 2]]
[1mROLLBACK[0m
Rendered photos/create.json.erb (0.0ms)

def create
  @photo = current_user.photos.build(photo_params)
end

<%= form_for :photo, url: photos_path, html: {class: 'dropzone', id: 'dropform' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
<% end %>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    $("#dropform").dropzone({
        maxFilesize: 5,
        paramName: "photo[picture]",
        addRemoveLinks: false, 
    }); 
});
</script>
```

When a photo is added to the dropzone, there is a checkmark on it but it is not being entered into the database. There is no commit. There was an error before:

> ActionView::MissingTemplate - Missing template items/continue, application/continue with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :arb, :haml, :jbuilder]}.

so I made a `create.json.erb` file but I do not know what to put into it.

Also, to get to this point, I had to remove some validations from `photo.rb` because I was getting error messages like `include?`... I guess because data was being sent in json it couldn't read the validations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up that I actually didn't need a js.erb or json.erb file and don't need Breno's solution either. The problem was that I had validations that required some of the params to be submitted, for example, there was a `:title` validation and while `:title` is allowed to be `''` it still has to be passed in the form otherwise the photo can't be created. I was then able to simply use `json` to `render` in the controller.

Comment: Please look my new #edit and to a better answer show the models photo.rb and user.rb and in your `rails console` try to simulate the validation error. `photo = Photo.new(user_id:2, picture: nil) ; photo.save ; photo.errors`

Answer (score 1):

```
def create
    @photo = current_user.photos.build(photo_params)
    if @current_userphoto.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json{ render :json => PhotoPresenter.new(@photo).to_json, status: ok } 
      end
    end
end

#create a app/presenter/photo_presenter.rb

class PhotoPresenter
  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes

  def initialize(object)
    @photo = object
  end 

  def json
      {"asset": {
          "id": @photo.id,
          "name" => @photo.picture_identifier,
          "type": @photo.picture.content_type,
          "size": @photo.picture.size,
          "url" => @photo.picture.url,
          "imageURL": @photo.picture.try(:url),
          "accepted": true,

        }
      }
    end
end
```

## Edit

For your validates issues you have more than once solution

```
# photo.rb

class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :validate_off
  validates_presence_of :title, unless: Proc.new {|obj| obj.validate_off == true}

end

# photos_controller.rb

def create
    @photo = current_user.photos.build(photo_params)
    @photo.validate_off = true
    if @photo.save
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json{ render :json => PhotoPresenter.new(@photo).to_json, status: ok } 
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. This is better than trying to do something with create.json.erb or index.json.builder ?

Comment: You can choice one or other. I rather this implementation because in this way I can to manipulate in this class of ruby because I can include modules or others helpers

Comment: I am away from computer so can't check but will this help with being able to run the validations that I had to remove from the Photo model?

Comment: Tim after show me the error messages of validation.

Comment: please see my answer. i didn't end up needing this solution but it does help me better understand `json` and may be useful for the future so i am upvoting the answer.

Comment: I post a new answer #Edit. @TimmyVonHeiss Please let me know if this helped you